# What does it mean for gravity in $(2+1)$ dimensions to be topological?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, topological-field-theory

I have been studying gravity in $(2+1)$-dimensions and I have come across the idea that gravity in this lower-dimensional spacetime is topological but I haven’t been able to find a simple explanation for what this means so I apologise in advance if the answer is simple.

I believe a topological field theory is one which doesn’t depend on the metric tensor we use but what does topological gravity mean? Does it mean the Einstein-Hilbert action in $2+1$ is independent of the metric we use? If so, how would we be able to solve for the metric if it has no dynamics when we solve for its equations of motion? A notable solution is the BTZ black hole solution, but I am unsure how this is topological.

Comment: Have you read the papers referenced in a Wikipedia page [(2+1)-dimensional topological gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(2%2B1)-dimensional_topological_gravity), in particular the 1988 Witten paper?